# Hibernate, what will happen if beginTransaction won't be used?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, session, transactions

I'm using hibernate 5.2 for connection to `SQLite` library. I created a new `Session` and used `session.createNativeQuery("My sql").executeUpdate()` after what I closed my `Session`. Everything works fine, but I came across several examples where after creating `Session` they begin `Transaction`, perform `SQL` operations, commit `Transaction`, and close `Session`. But not all examples online have `Transaction` in them and my code works fine without it.

This made me curious:

- Why we need to use `Transaction`?
- What will happen if we won't?
- And most important, in which cases it needs to be used and in which
  not?

I use `<property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>`

Comment: That has nothing todo with Java or hibernate. Transaction is a db thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try relating hibernate with JDBC and you will be getting some hints about transaction.

In JDBC you need to just open a connection start your work, and in the end you can commit or rollback.

But what if you have many different parallel tasks , which may be dependent or independent to each other. Then you may require commit/rollback each task separately or rollback if any fails.

```
for example
Big Task :
    small task1
    small task2
    small task3 and many more
```

rollback the big task if any small task fails.This can be one of the many business requirements.

In JDBC, Connection interface has provided commit() and rollback() methods.

In jpa/hibernate, Transaction interface has provided commit() and rollback() methods.

So one session can have many dependent or independent transactions.

Below is documentation from org.hibernate.Transaction

```
Allows the application to define units of work, while maintaining 
abstraction from the underlying transaction implementation (eg. JTA, JDBC). 

A transaction is associated with a Session and is usually 
initiated by a call to org.hibernate.Session.beginTransaction(). 
A single session might span multiple transactions since the notion of a session 
(a conversation between the application and the datastore) is of coarser granularity 
than the notion of a transaction. However, it is intended that there be at most 
one uncommitted transaction associated with a particular Session at any time.
```

This also might help you 
[What is the difference between a session and a transaction in JPA 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409085/what-is-the-difference-between-a-session-and-a-transaction-in-jpa-2-0)

Answer (score 1):

Why we need to use Transaction?
-> What you are doing is just a simple update, transaction mgmt is used in case there are multiple updates and you want ACID nature for your transaction.

What will happen if we won't?
-> If there are multiple update statements and one of them throws an exception you will have inconsistent data.

Comment: I was executing several `SQL` queries without `Transaction` and it went fine. Can you tell a bit more about case it can go wrong?

Comment: Alyona there are concepts like conflict serializable, dhanajay is referring to those

Answer (score 0):

Let's define what is transaction - basically it is atomic unit of work.

There are two types of transaction management or transaction demarcation(think of demarcation as of starting transaction, committing or rolling transaction back) : CMT (container managed transactions) - managed by underlying container for you (JTA) and BMT(bean managed transactions) - transaction demarcation is managed programmatically by developer itself. So if you see in any example that `transaction` is obtained and programmatically committed or rolled back - that is example of BMT, that is when it is your responsibility of a developer to manage transaction.

Whenever you do not see explicit transaction demarcation - that means that is is CMT. 
This is very broad subject - I advise you to [read more.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnciy.html)